# Testing variants against each other

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to get unused values in the textbox, currently i get all of them, se below

[image: The result i get..]

This is what I´m trying to get..

[image: Goal..]

..and finally(don't know how to formulate the question yet) this..

[image: Final goal..]

My code so far..
It fails to recognize any matches on line 21 (If x = y Then match = True)

```
    Option Explicit
Sub Resources()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Arr = Range("A2:A10").Value

    Dim varr As Variant
    varr = Application.Transpose(ExtractNumbers(Range("C2:E10")))

    ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text = "Unused values"

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, z As Variant
    Dim match As Boolean

    For Each x In Arr
        match = False
        For Each y In varr
            If x = y Then match = True
        Next y

        If Not match And x > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text = ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text & Chr(10) & x
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Function ExtractNumbers(Target As Range) As Variant
    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim regExMatches As Object, regExMatch As Object
    Dim Result As String
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = "[0-9]+"
            End With

            Set regExMatches = regEx.Execute(Cell.Value)
            For Each regExMatch In regExMatches
                Result = Result & regExMatch & ", "
            Next regExMatch
        End If
    Next Cell
    ExtractNumbers = Split(Left$(Result, Len(Result) - 1), ", ")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Collect the values into a vbLF delimited list before depositing them onto the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub resources()
    Dim i As Long, str As String
    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        'collect the missing
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Not CBool(Application.CountIf(.Range("C:E"), .Cells(i, "A").Value)) Then
                str = Chr(10) & .Cells(i, "A").Value & Space(1) & .Cells(i, "B").Value & str
            End If
        Next i

        'put results in merged cell
        If CBool(Len(str)) Then
            str = "unused values" & str
            .Range("F:F").UnMerge
            .Cells(1, "F").Resize(UBound(Split(str, Chr(10))) + 1, 1).Merge
            .Cells(1, "F").WrapText = True
            .Cells(1, "F") = str
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Nice testing method, sadly I can't have the result in cells

Comment: Then `dim arr as variant: arr = split(str, chr(10))` to create a nice variant array.

Comment: Well.. maybe my imagination is lacking but i can't wrap my head around how i can combine or implement this with my code without causing more problems. Tried to simplify my question since no one answered in my first attempt, but it was probably too much and my images is probably misleading since I need the ExtractNumbers part to remain for cells containing more than one integer in the 
 C:E range. My question should probably have been "why doesn't any x's match with any y's" Thank you anyway! :)